# Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса к серверу

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема. При долгом зависании страницы через 90 секунд, она обновляется и нечего не происходит. Например если я нажал кнопку и что то должно было произойти, допустим выполниться запрос или ещё что то. И это происходит больше чем 90 секунд. То происходит то что я описал. Если отследить это в дебаге. То вылетает следующий экзепшен, просто по истечении 90 секунд. Если даже просто запустить, нечего не делать, а потом нажать f10 что бы перейти к следующей строчке. Вот экзепшен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На просторах stackoverflow нашёл вот что для решения этой проблемы:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 300;
```

Эта строчка пишется в page_load. Но мне нужен другой вариант. Возможно же увеличить тайм-аут настройками? Например в веб конфиге или ещё где в настройках сервера. Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает как это можно сделать.

Comment: Да, в конфиге можно. Но решать проблему нужно не установкой таймаута ;)

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev нужно именно это решение. Подскажите как это выставить в конфиге? Если вы про строчку <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" />, то это не тот тайм-аут, потому что он не работает на то что я описал. И в строке подключение коннекшен тайм аут тоже не то.

Comment: А с shutdownTimeout пробовал экспериментировать?

Comment: @Михаил нет, не пробовал, не приведёте пример если не сложно?

Comment: <httpRuntime shutdownTimeout="300" /> :)

Comment: @Михаил попробовал. Спасибо за подсказку, но это тоже не то. Пока сработал только тот вариант что я написал. Но он делается либо в коде cs-ника либо в asp-разметке. Для конфига пока не нашёл подходящего варианта. Если кто то в курсе подскажите пожалуйста.